# Rvalue ref and perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I've read few papers about && and I'm just curious if having:

```
void fnc_1(int&& p)
{
//...
}

void fnc(int&& r)
{
fnc_1(r);//am I suppose to/should I? call it like so:fnc_1(std::forward(r)) 
}
```

or just passing 'r' is enough?

Comment: Is your first function `fnc_1` ? If not, we should see it: its signature matters.

Answer (score 6):

`fnc_1(r)` won't compile, because `r` is an lvalue, just like any other variable, regardless of type. Yes, that's right, named rvalue references are lvalues, not rvalues.

`fnc_1(std::forward(r))` also won't compile, because `std::forward` is specifically designed not to infer its template argument.

To pass an rvalue, either of the following would work:

```
fnc_1(std::move(r))
fnc_1(std::forward<int&&>(r))  
fnc_1(std::forward<int>(r))
```

Using `std::move` is the idiomatic way to cast an lvalue to an rvalue, so I would recommend using that.

Comment: and of course the old `static_cast<int&&>(r)` will also work, though it's too much typing.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::forward` template is usually for dependent types. Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) carefully to see whether it applies here. This is a difficult subject to master, so feel free to update your question with relevant details about your exact problem (using rvalue references for integers isn't terribly exciting...).

I believe your question is about the understanding of the basic properties of rvalue references. The rule of thumb to remember is:

- whatever has a name is a lvalue (const or not).
- whatever has no name is a rvalue.
- Types with `&&` bind to rvalues.

If you have a function...

```
void foo(SomeClass&& x)
{
    // ... then here x has type SomeClass& !
}
```

then inside the body, `x` is a name, and therefore a **l** value. It really has type `SomeClass&`. You must use `std::move` to turn a `SomeClass&` into `SomeClass&&`:

```
void bar(SomeClass&& x)
{
    // Since `x` has a name here, it is a Lvalue.
    // Therefore it has type SomeClass&, what the signature doesn't indicate.

    // We thus have to explicitly turn it into a rvalue:
    foo(std::move(x));
}
```

Comment: Isn't the program is ill formed because reference to a reference is not allowed in C++?

Comment: @Alex I've typed int just as an example, in my code it is a class template

Comment: @Als: this is not a reference to reference, it is a *rvalue reference* (something from the future C++ standard).

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Aha! Thanks..I missed that, Also the Q was never tagged, `C++0x`, I shall do that now.

Comment: @smallB: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward and discuss what you don't understand. There is a lot of quite difficult things to grasp before using rvalue references and perfect forwarding.

Comment: @Alexandre I think you meant `void bar(SomeClass & x)` to illustrate how `std::move()` creates an rvalue-ref from a ref.

Comment: @Richard: inside the body of `bar`, `x` has type `SomeClass&`, not `SomeClass&&`. This is the first thing to remember about rvalue references. Let me clarify this point in the answer's body.