# What is the type of a named rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, decltype

Consider the following code:

```
int&& x = 42;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype( x ), int&&>::value, "&&");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype((x)), int& >::value, "&" );
```

So, what is the type of `x`? Is it an `int&&` or an `int&`?

(I asked myself this question after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862639/rvalue-ref-and-perfect-forwarding/6862677#6862677).)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The type of `x` (of the variable) is `int&&`. So `decltype(x)` yields `int&&`. The type of the expression `x` is `int`. If the expression is an lvalue, `decltype((x))` yields a lvalue reference to the type of the expression. So `decltype((x))` yields `int&`.